# Elasticsearch list indices sorted by name

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aliases

How can the following query's results be sorted by index name?

```
curl "localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty"
```

Comment: Can't you sort by your own? I don't think it exists.

Comment: @ErBnAcharya The result has no field name to specify.

Comment: @ErBnAcharya How is that done?

Comment: have you tried `curl localhost:9200/_cat/aliases | sort`?  I realize it's a completely different format, but it might be what you really wanted

Comment: I recommend to use `sort` as @Alcanzar said. Try `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -nk2`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that the best way to do this would be via the console. Something like this:

`$ curl --silent 'http://path.to.cluster:9200/_cat/indices' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sort`

Comment: Ah, nice.  I've changed it slightly to: `curl --silent 'http://path.to.cluster:9200/_cat/aliases' | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort`

Comment: I had to change the cut to use `-f3` instead of `-f2`.

Comment: You can use `-n(numeric sort)` option and `-k(key)` option for `sort` instead of using `cut`. For example, `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices' | sort -nk 3`

Comment: How to sort in descending order using the above solution ?

Comment: I had to use `awk` because the spaces delimiting each column where not constant for me: `$ curl --silent 'http://path.to.cluster:9200/_cat/indices' | awk '{ print $3 }' | sort`

Comment: @Rupesh: `sort --reverse`

Answer (score 91):

You can ask ES to sort the results via the `s` (sort) searchParameter using `s=i` or `s=index`

```
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty&s=i"
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/aliases?pretty&s=index"
```

To see the column's headers, add "&v" :

```
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty&v&s=index"`.
```

You can find some explanations in the [cat/indices documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/reference/cat/indices.asciidoc)

Comment: what do you mean ? curl is just doing an http request, you can use it in a browser or with any http client in any language

Comment: I couldn't get any of these to work via a postman get on ES 5.2+.  I get 400 response "illegal_argument_exception, request [/_aliases/] contains unrecognized parameter: [s]"

Comment: You can also change the sort order: `/_cat/indices?v&s=docs.count:desc`

Answer (score 27):

### The best way for Elasticsearch 5x is like this:

```
GET _cat/aliases?v&s=index:desc&h=alias,index
```

Will give you:

```
alias                                     index
app-logs-alias                            app-logs-2017-12-31
backend-logs-read                         backend-logs-2017-12-31
```

> *s = sort, v = various extra detail, h = headings to include,*

Comment: Plus +1 hands up for reverse ordering

Comment: This answer tells about so many features in a very clean fashion.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, but now in 2020 the best way is :

with kibana :

```
GET _cat/indices/?pretty&s=store.size:desc
```

with curl :

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?pretty&s=store.size:desc
```

Desc at the end for sort by desc

Answer (score 3):

Just use this get request it will show all indexes with the column name.

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?pretty&v
```

Additionally, not only by name you can sort it by any parameter you want with a get parameter of `s=column_name`.

for example; to sort by the size you can do like:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?pretty&s=store.size
```

similarly for name:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?pretty&s=index
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it exists by elasticsearch api.

Response from elasticsearch can be

```
{
   "index1": {
      "aliases": {}
   }
}
```

Here is a pseudocode to get index from response

If aliasresponse is response from elasticsearch, then

```
indexlist=[]
for (key in aliasresponse) {
    indexlist.add(key)
}

sort(indexlist)
```

For sorting, you can find libaries or custom methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I'm interested to see if there's an api alternative.  Along with simple re-indexing such as _copy myindex testindex_ ( https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1077 closed? ) there seem to be some unexpected omissions.